# Script to save settings

Tags: greasemonkey, scriptish

Is there a way to save some settings to the local computer that is not cookies with a user script?

It is difficult to make a user script that is for multiple domains if the settings are not global.

From a comment: `"I am using scriptish "`.

Comment: Clarify. You want to have settings that apply across multiple domains?  Is it OK if the settings are kept in a hand-edited file, or must the script be able to set them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Absolutely, it's very easy. The [Greasemonkey wiki](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Main_Page) documents four methods that allow you to deal with saving values, which can be settings or anything else you want to store:

- [GM_setValue(name, string)](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue)
- [GM_getValue(name[, default])](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getValue)
- [GM_deleteValue(name)](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_deleteValue)
- [GM_listValues()](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_listValues)

You might want to check out the [main API](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual:API) page for other useful methods, and there's also a complete [metadata block documentation](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block) page.

The only way this might not work is in a Google Chrome Content Script. There are a few solutions though: you can either use the [Google Chrome GM_*](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/68559) userscript in addition to yours, or you can make the GM_setValue and GM_getValue methods available by including this at the beginning of your user script (from [Devine.me](http://devign.me/greasemonkey-gm_getvaluegm_setvalue-functions-for-google-chrome/)):

```
if (!this.GM_getValue || (this.GM_getValue.toString && this.GM_getValue.toString().indexOf("not supported")>-1)) {
    this.GM_getValue=function (key,def) {
        return localStorage[key] || def;
    };
    this.GM_setValue=function (key,value) {
        return localStorage[key]=value;
    };
    this.GM_deleteValue=function (key) {
        return delete localStorage[key];
    };
}
```

Comment: does the second function really needs to return something ? It seems that only `localStorage[key]=value;` without return before would work.